What are some numbers that seem irrational/transcendental because of the way they look but actually aren't?
It is not known whether $\pi+e, \pi-e, \frac{\pi}{e}, etc$ are irrational, it has also been shown that at least one of the numbers $\zeta(5), \zeta(7), \zeta(9), \zeta(11)$ is irrational. From my point of view, it looks "obvious" that all these numbers are irrational however proving them is a different story. Do you know of any numbers that seem irrational/transcendental at first glance but actually aren't? (except $e^{i\pi}$)

See this question

See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32967/have-any-long-suspected-irrational-numbers-turned-out-to-be-rational

Dobinski's formula looks like it could produce something, but not necessarily an integer (I think) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula

The followings of hypergeometric function might be such examples.
$${}_2F_1\bigg(\frac 18,\frac 18;\frac 12;-2400\bigg)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac 18)_n(\frac 18)_n}{(\frac 12)_n}\frac{(-2400)^n}{n!}=\frac 23$$
$${}_2F_1\bigg(\frac 38,\frac 38;\frac 12;-2400\bigg)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac 38)_n(\frac 38)_n}{(\frac 12)_n}\frac{(-2400)^n}{n!}=\frac{2}{21}$$
where ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function and $(q)_n$ is the (rising) Pochhammer symbol whose definition is
$$(q)_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $n=0$}\\ q(q+1)\cdots (q+n-1)&\text{if $n\gt 0$}\end{cases}$$
So, for example, we have
$$\bigg(\frac 18\bigg)_n=\frac 18\bigg(\frac 18+1\bigg)\cdots \bigg(\frac 18+n-1\bigg)=\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac 18)}{\Gamma(\frac 18)}$$
You can see the other examples here.
(You might also want to see (18)(19) here which are written in this answer to the question Jair Taylor wrote in a comment.)

Added :
The followings also might be such examples.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\frac{1}{n+1}=2$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac 43$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\frac{1}{n+3}=\frac{16}{15}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\bigg(\frac 14\bigg)^n\frac{1}{n+4}=\frac{32}{35}$$
By the way, the followings are similar but not rational.
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^5(-256)^{n}\frac{2(10n^2+14n+5)}{7(2n+1)^5}=ζ(3)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\bigg(\frac 1{256}\bigg)^n\frac{6n+1}{4}=\frac{1}{\pi}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\right)^7(256)^n\frac{16(21n^3+41n^2+27n+6)}{(2n+1)^7}=π^4$$

idk about the po's hammer symbol thing but i like the direction of this answer

@uggupuggu : I added more examples. (Also I added an explanation about the Pochhammer symbol.)

Sorry for the late reply, was busy. I like the sums, but Ill wait and see if there are any more answers

The problem is that any rational number can be written, by defintion, under the simple closed form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ integers. What you actually look for, I guess, is mathematical expression which look irrational but actually equal a rational number.
You can find convoluted expressions with roots like the one shared by J.-E. Pin,
$$
\sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3} = 1.
$$
A good way to generate them is to use Cardano's formula for cubic equations. If $p,q$ are real numbers with $-\Delta = \frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} > 0$, then the equation $t^3 + pt + q = 0$ has one unique real solution,
$$
t = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} + \sqrt{-\Delta}} + \sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{-\Delta}}.
$$
Similar results exist to find the complex roots when $-\Delta > 0$ and all three real roots when $-\Delta \leqslant 0$ but it doesn't matter here. Now, take a rational number, $r$. Take a complex number $z$ and develop the following real degree $3$ polynomial,
\begin{align*}
(t - r)(t - z)(t - \overline{z}) & = (t - r)(t^2 - 2\Re(z)t + |z|^2)\\
& = t^3 - (r + 2\Re(z))t^2 + (2r\Re(z) + |z|^2)t - r|z|^2.
\end{align*}
We want the term in $t^2$ to vanish so $\Re(z) = -\frac{r}{2}$. The condition $-\Delta > 0$ is automatically fulfilled if $\Im(z) \neq 0$ because it is equivalent of having only one real root. All the equalities that follow remain true when $\Im(z) = 0$ by continuity.
We have $p = 2r\Re(z) + |z|^2 = -r^2 + |z|^2$ and $q = -r|z|^2$ so,
$$
-\Delta = \frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} = \frac{r^2|z|^4}{4} + \frac{(|z|^2 - r^2)^3}{27} = \frac{r^2|z|^4}{4} + \frac{|\Im(z)|^6}{27}.
$$
It is, as expected, positive, and by Cardano's formula,
$$
r = \sqrt[3]{\frac{r|z|^2}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{r^2|z|^4}{4} + \frac{|\Im(z)|^6}{27}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{r|z|^2}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{r^2|z|^4}{4} + \frac{|\Im(z)|^6}{27}}}.
$$
For example, with $r = 2$ and $z = 1 - i$,
$$
2 = \sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{\frac{100}{27}}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{\frac{100}{27}}} = \sqrt[3]{2 + \frac{10}{9}\sqrt{3}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \frac{10}{9}\sqrt{3}}
$$
Or with $r = \frac{2}{3}$ and $z = -\frac{1}{3} + \sqrt[4]{5}$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{3} = & \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{9} + \sqrt{5}\right) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1}{9} + \sqrt{5}\right)^2 + \frac{\sqrt{125}}{27}}} + (\cdots)\\
& = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{\frac{406}{729} + \frac{17}{81}\sqrt{5}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{\frac{406}{729} + \frac{17}{81}\sqrt{5}}}.
\end{align*}
It is not related but you also have the famous,
$$
\left(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\right)^{\sqrt{2}} = 2.
$$

I like this answer however I was looking for something that didn't just involve simplifying radicals. It would be really easy to show this is rational with a calculator. To me, an answer would be more complex. For instance, imagine if one day zeta(7) is proven to be rational, that would be a good answer.

One example might be the number $$1 / 9899 = .00010102030508132135\ldots$$ given by concatenating the Fibonacci numbers $1,2,3,5,8,13,21,35, \ldots$ (although the pattern breaks down slightly when the Fibonacci numbers require more than two digits.)
